# AWS Lambda not firing nodejs request module

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to execute Lambda function that has the request module. Unfortunately, it is not firing the request module. Neither does it give any error in the cloudwatch logs.

Request your help, what could be the issue for which this request module is not fired. This works using Postman.

Nodejs Version Used: 8.10

```
request({
      url: 'https://api.amazon.com/user/profile',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ bearerTok,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }, function(err, res) {
          if(err) {
            console.error("Error"+err);
          } else {
            console.log("Result+"+res.body);
            callback( res.body);
          }

    });
```

Comment: Try generating code snippets using postman itself. Try [this](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/) for more info

Comment: Is this all that is inside your Lambda file? Where is the `handler`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what type of METHOD it is. 
`method : "TYPE"`

```
{
  method : "GET",
  url: 'https://api.amazon.com/user/profile',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ bearerTok,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```